# PHP : Function to convert the date format

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

I want to convert the date format from a particular format to some other.

For example,

**Convert the date from ( 2011-06-21 or 2011/06/21 or 06/21/2011 ) to 21062011.**

Is there any function to do this job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 : So many duplicates are available....!!!!!

[ http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+php ]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump(
    date('dmY', strtotime('2011-06-21')),
    date('dmY', strtotime('2011/06/21')),
    date('dmY', strtotime('06/21/2011'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime) class.

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-06-21');
echo $date->format('dmY');
```

It can be used procedurally, if you wish.

```
var_dump(
    date_format(date_create('2011-06-21'), 'dmY'),
    date_format(date_create('2011/06/21'), 'dmY'),
    date_format(date_create('06/21/2011'), 'dmY')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should be able to to use date combined with strtotime like so

```
$date; //the date that needs to be formatted
<?php date('dmY', strtotime($date)); ?>
```

So inside the date() function you simply format the date however you want the original date to be

[php strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dates are very locale specific. strtotime() does not observe all of the niceties of the locale (and date_parse is a simple wrapper around strtotime). e.g. today is 21/06/2011 in the UK, and 06/21/2011 in the US.

A more robust solution is to use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

However, IME, unless you are sourcing the input data from a consistent machine generated source, a better solution is to use a tool which facilitates [input in a consistent format](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)