# How to convert MYSQL date field into the following format in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP convert one date into another date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

2011-09-06 needs to be converted to a format like 2011-09-06T00:00:00.0000000

I did Google it and I was not clear on the the solutions.

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: There are about 3,000 questions on Stack Overflow that deal with converting one date to the other in PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+convert+date

Comment: See e.g. [PHP : Function to convert the date format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6421304)

Comment: Anyway, what you need is 1. strtotime() http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: And 2. date() http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going too deep into a well-documented problem, or trying to figure out where you are confused, some things to consider are:

1. Converting the DATE field in your table to a DATETIME field
2. Selecting the date field using the [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function.
3. Using PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert the format to the way you like.

Comment: Number 2 did it for me. Thanks for being positive.